# How to speed up color quantization via kmeans clustering

Tags: python, opencv, k-means

I'm trying to speed up my implementation of "kmeans" clustering to minimize the number of colors in the image yet keep it pretty. It's extremely slow on the image 1000x1000 with k=32. But the function gives a perfect color/tone match (which is crucial) in comparison with the other tested approaches so I could not find any equivalent replacement for it (if any?).

I had an idea to resize the image before the clustering process (e.g. make 300x300), then use the reduced color palette for the original image, but my python knowledge is not enough to make that within the function. Could you please help?

This is my original slow function  (I commented out my experimental attempts):

```
def color_quantize(image, K):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    Z = img.reshape((-1, 3))

    # *** my attempt to resize to a smaller size for clustering
    #thumbnail = cv2.resize(img, (300, 300), cv2.INTER_CUBIC)             
    #​Z = thumbnail.reshape((-1, 3))

    Z = np.float32(Z)

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 15, 1.0)
    ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(Z, K, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
    
    center = np.uint8(center)
    res = center[label.flatten()]

    # *** here should go some backward process to apply the reduced color palette to the original image...

    quantized_img = res.reshape(img.shape)

    quantized_img = cv2.cvtColor(quantized_img, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    return quantized_img
```

### UPDATE

After lots of attempts to find a solution which gives good coloring and fast speed I ended up with the following:

```
def color_quantize_fast(image, K):
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img))
im_pil = im_pil.quantize(K, None, 0, None)
return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(im_pil.convert("RGB")), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

It accepts image in format cv2.imread() returns. And it returns a quantized image in a similar format back.
K is the number of colors (1 <= K <= 255)

Comment: opencv comes with a ton of tutorials right on docs.opencv.org and I'm sure you can figure out `cv.resize` from that. as for the decimation idea... you use it ONLY for finding the cluster centers. to apply this to your full-size picture, you obviously have to find the "nearest neighbor" for every pixel's color. that is a lot easier than the clustering itself.

Comment: cv2.resize is not an issue. The problem is how to use cluster data against the original (full size) image once it's done due to different array dimensions of the original image and "label"/"center" arrays of resized image. 
This part is not covered by a tutorial, I've checked it and StackOverflow on a similar topic.

Comment: see about stuffing those clusters into FLANN (FlannBasedMatcher), then do a nearest neighbor query for every pixel. you can express that completely with numpy too. involves a subtraction, np.linalg.norm, and an argmin. calling `.train()` on a flannbasedmatcher gave me some trouble some while ago, so I had to pass the "training" data every time. might have been a resolved bug or an issue with python bindings, IDK. https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html